# Calculate date difference to get output without round off in SQLDB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate date difference between two dates and output will be without roundoff in SQL DB.

```
Date1: 2017-07-16 16:01:00.0000000
Date2: 2017-10-10 00:00:00.0000000
output would be: 85,3326388888891
```

I wrote sql query as like but didn't get the exact result:

```
select (datediff(d, '2017-07-16 16:01:00.0000000', '2017-10-10 00:00:00.0000000'))
```

and got `86` as output.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17277.0

Comment: how this is arrived? 3326388888891 , what does it correspond to ?

Comment: FYI the version of SSMS is not relevant, its only a client interface. Its the version of the database engine you want `select @@version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get the expected result using the following statement, but the important question is why do you need such a calculation (days between two dates, based on the differences in seconds or minutes):

```
SELECT 
    (datediff(second, '2017-07-16 16:01:00.0000000', '2017-10-10 00:00:00.0000000')) / 
    (24.0 * 60 * 60)
--or
SELECT 
    (datediff(minute, '2017-07-16 16:01:00.0000000', '2017-10-10 00:00:00.0000000')) / 
    (24.0 * 60)
```

Results:

```
85.3326388888
85.3326388
```

Comment: We can go for DATEDIFF_BIG for bigger number differences. The return type is `BIGINT`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-big-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15